# Difference Between localhost 8888 and 8890

Tags: shell, jupyter

I was wondering what the 8888 and 8889 number means when I launch a jupyter notebook in my browser (I'm launching the notebook via Anaconda Navigator). I noticed how the number increases by 1 (from 8888 to 8889, to 8891) as I launch more notebooks from my anaconda navigator, but the files I have access to are exactly the same. Why then have different numbers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are launching a new process which uses an unused port. The first start will use port `8888`, the second (if the process is active) will use port `8889` and so on.

Note: this is just for Jupyter. Other applications may exit with an error code stating the "port is already in use".

Comment: Thanks for this. I think my confusion was mainly that I didn't understand what ports were. If anyone is confused was confused with this as well, I would recommend googling ports.